# Java Error: The constructor C17PacketCustomPayload(String, byte[]) is undefined

Tags: java

Why I am getting this error?

> **The constructor C17PacketCustomPayload(String, byte[]) is undefined**

Java Code:

```
package pw.cinque.ping;

import java.awt.Color;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

import net.minecraft.network.Packet;

import net.minecraft.network.PacketBuffer;

import net.minecraft.network.play.client.C17PacketCustomPayload;

import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.InputEvent;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;

import java.awt.*;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

@Mod(modid = Packets.MODID, version = Packets.VERSION)
public class Packets
{
    public static final String MODID = "Lower ur ping!";

    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    private static final Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();

    private boolean textGui;

    private final int textGuiKey = Keyboard.KEY_P;

    private boolean reachToogle;

    private final int reachKey = Keyboard.KEY_L;

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        FMLCommonHandler.instance().bus().register(this);

        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);

        System.out.println("Intialized Reach Mod by Shiny");
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onRender(TickEvent.RenderTickEvent e) {

        if(textGui)

            mc.fontRendererObj.drawStringWithShadow("Shiny", 2, 2, Color.BLACK.hashCode());

    }


    @SubscribeEvent
    public void  onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent e) {

        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(textGuiKey)) {

            textGui = !textGui;

            return;

        }
        else if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(reachKey)) {

                 reachToogle = !reachToogle;
             }

        Packet spoofedReachPacket = manipulateReachPacket(spoofReachValue(4.2));

        mc.thePlayer.sendQueue.addToSendQueue(spoofedReachPacket);
    }

    private Packet manipulateReachPacket(byte[] spoofedReachValue) {

        return new C17PacketCustomPayload("reach", spoofedReachValue);
    }

    private byte[] spoofReachValue(double reachValue) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8];

        ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).putDouble(reachValue`enter code here`);

        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: What constructors _does_ `C17PacketCustomPayload` have?

Comment: I'm guessing that it means that that constructor isn't defined. What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're getting your error here:

```
return new C17PacketCustomPayload("reach", spoofedReachValue);
```

It's saying that the constructor is undefined which means the class C17PacketCustomPayload does not have a constructor that takes a string and/or byte[] as arguments. If you created this class yourself then you need to add a method that looks like this

```
public C17PacketCustomPayload(String string, byte[] bytes){
//add behavior here
}
```

If you didn't create this class but are merely importing, then you need to look up just what parameters this constructor takes and fix it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Why I am getting this error?

The answer is evident from these reverse engineered [javadocs](https://takahikokawasaki.github.io/minecraft-resources/javadoc/forge/1.8-11.14.1.1320/net/minecraft/network/play/client/C17PacketCustomPayload.html).

```
Constructors:

C17PacketCustomPayload() 
C17PacketCustomPayload(java.lang.String p1, PacketBuffer p1)
```

In your code, the second parameter to the constructor call needs to be a `PacketBuffer` object, not a `byte[]`.